# PHP / AJAX checkbox values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to get all checked checkbox values and parse them to my php functin using AJAX.

I use foreach to try and get each id of the checked checkbox's.

My problem is that when I try and update the database, it doesn't return '1' which I echo upon success.

When I take my foreach code out, it works.

***My delete button is :***

```
<form class="form -dark" id="form-inline" method="POST">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" onclick="deleteSelectedTokens()" class="btn -dark" style="margin-left: 5px;" title="Delete all selected tokens"><i class="fa fa-trash"> </i></a>
    </div>
</form>
```

***My checkbox html/php code is :***

```
<table class="table -dark -striped">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th style="text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox" id="selectall"/></th>
        <th style="text-align: center;">Token</th>
        <th style="text-align: center;">Date/Time Generated</th>
        <th style="text-align: center;">Status</th>
        <th style="text-align: center;">Durbaility</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
        <?php

        $username = $_SESSION['username'];
        $token_result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id, token, used, time_generated, durability FROM tokens WHERE user_id = '$username' ORDER BY used");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($token_result) > 0) {
            while($token_row = mysqli_fetch_array($token_result)) {

            $result = array($token_row['durability']); $sub_struct_month = ($result[0] / 30) ; $sub_struct_month = floor($sub_struct_month); $sub_struct_days = ($result[0] % 30); $sub_struct = "<i>".$sub_struct_month."</i> month(s) <i>".$sub_struct_days."</i> day(s)";

            echo '                  
            <tr style="text-align: center;">
            <td>
            <center><input type="checkbox" id="checkedTokens" class="checkbox" value='.($token_row['id']).'></center>
            </td>
            <td>
            '.$token_row['token'].'
            </td>
            <td>
            '.($token_row['time_generated']).'
            </td>
            <td>
            '.($token_row['used'] == "0" ? "<span class='label label-primary'><i class='fa fa-check'></i> Valid </span>" : "<span class='label label-primary'><i class='fa fa-fa fa-times'></i> Used </span>").'
            </td>
            <td>
            '.$sub_struct.'
            </td>
            ';
             } }else{ ?>

             <tr>
             <td colspan="12" style="padding: 30px;">
             <div class="alert -dark">
                <div class="alert-icon _text-danger">
                    <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                </div>
                No tokens in your account
            </div>
            </td>
            </tr>

            <?php } ?>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
```

Notice I need to use foreach to get each check checkbox value so I can remove the selected ones when I press the delete button.

***My AJAX send to PHP function is :***

```
<script>
function deleteSelectedTokens() {
  var selectedTokens = document.getElementById("checkedTokens").value;

  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "includes/form_submit.php",
      data: {
        deleteSelectedTkns: true,
        checked_id: selectedTokens
      },
      success: function(msg){
        if(msg == 1) {
          update_myDays_success();
        } else {
          general_error_forms();
        }
      },
  });
return false;
}
</script>
```

I think the problem is the Javascript... when I get the value of the checkboxes and post them, i think it's only getting 1 value inside the checkedTokens id.

***My php receive code (this is not the problem) :***

```
$username       = $_SESSION['username'];
$selectedTokens = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['checked_id']);
foreach($selectedTokens as $id) {
    $doUpdateDelete = 'DELETE FROM tokens WHERE id = "'.$id.'" AND user_id = "'.$username.'"';
    $result = $con->query($doUpdateDelete) or die("Error");
    if($result)
    {
        echo '1';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Failed';
    }
}
```

My console.log has not errors. Like I said, i think it's the javascript code for getting the value of my checkbox's not getting all the values.

Comment: You are repeating the id to multiple checkboxes, this is not the way you get all the checkbox values, please be specific with your `ids` i.e. they should not be the same for all elements.

Comment: @FarrukhAyyaz No, I'm using the id's of each row in my database for the value of each textbox.

Comment: In your code the checkbox ids, your assigning and using in your javascript are identical to each checkbox. Its not your table ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send json of checked items:

```
<script>
    var selectedTokens = []; 
    $('#checkedTokens:checked').each(function(key, value){
        selectedTokens.push($(value).val());
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "includes/form_submit.php",
        data: {
           deleteSelectedTkns: true,
           checked_id: JSON.stringify(selectedTokens)
    },
    success: function(msg){
      if(msg == 1) {
        update_myDays_success();
      } else {
        general_error_forms();
      }
    },
  });
  </script>
```

And your php code mysqli_real_escape_string give only string we should convert json to get array:

```
$selectedTokens = json_decode($_POST['checked_id']); 
foreach($selectedTokens as $id) {
    $doUpdateDelete = 'DELETE FROM tokens WHERE id = "'.$id.'" AND user_id = "'.$username.'"';
    $result = $con->query($doUpdateDelete) or die("Error");
    if($result)
    {
        echo '1';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Failed';
    } 
}
```

Comment: Wow. It worked perfectly! How do you know this would work ? Can you explain why it works.

Comment: When you send data between client and server to send, use JSON or XML. 
You get value of checked items. And convert to json.
On the server you get json and convert to object.

Answer (score 0):

In html it is not allowed to assign the same id to multiple tags. (As already mentioned in the comments.)

If you place your checkboxes on a `<form id="some_id">`, and give every checkbox a unique name and id, you can use the function `$('#some_id').serialize()` to get the data of the form and post it to the server.